# How to remove values smaller than a given value but not the last?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I think the example is the simplest.
I have this array : [10, 30, 55, 75, 94, 112] and the value 69.
I want to get: [55, 75, 94, 112]

So I want to filter out the smaller values but keep the closest.

an idea?

Comment: Where did you get stuck when you tried this?

Comment: Is the array always sorted?

Comment: Why not 7,9,11?

Comment: because  5 is the first value smaller than target

Comment: Yeah that, but 7 is just as close.  :)

Comment: but its not smaller

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.filter, Array.pop, Array.sort Array.concat

```
function f(val, array){
  // array.sort( (a,b)=>a-b ); // if array isn't sorted, you must be use
  return array.filter(e=>e>val).concat([array.filter(e=>e<val).pop()])
}
```

Comment: yo don't need the `sort` since input is sorted? but this one liner gets my vote :p

Comment: Hmmm  i have forget .

Comment: Does not work if the value is 113.
[array.filter(e=>e<=val).pop()].concat(array.filter(e=>e>val))

Comment: @1811L2201DA i updated solution, Array.prototype.sort mehtod isn't sorting when callback function not given. I update `.sort((a,b)=>a-b)`

Comment: @HasanDelibaş - it is sorting, just not numerically :p

Answer (score 1):

Something like this using filter.

```
  var arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11];
  var value = 6;

  function remove(arr, value) {
    let copy = arr;
    let newArr = arr.filter((arr, index) => !((arr < value) && (copy[index + 1] < value)))
    console.log(newArr)
  }

  remove(arr, value) // [5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter, and check if either this or the next value in the array is >= limit

```js
const filter=(array, limit)=>array.filter((value,index)=>value>=limit||array[index+1]>limit);

console.log(filter([10, 30, 55, 75, 94, 112], 69));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible approach (apparently assuming array is sorted). The idea is to find the very first item that is greater than or equal to `lim`; when you found it, there's no need to check the rest of an array (and that's what all the other answers do).

```js
function processSorted(arr, lim) {
  const i = arr.findIndex(el => el >= lim);
  if (i === -1)  // no elements greater than lim, return just the last one
    return arr.slice(-1);
  if (i === 0)  // the first element is greater than lim, give back 'em all!
    return arr;
  return arr.slice(i - 1);
}
console.log(processSorted([10, 30, 55, 75, 94, 112], 69));
```

It's not sorted, it's possible to sort it anyway, or, if you really strive for n-only, go with one-iteration only approach:

```js
function processUnsorted(arr, lim) {
  const res = [];
  let oneLess = -Infinity, 
      len = arr.length;
  arr.forEach(el => {
    if (el >= lim) res.push(el);
    else oneLess = Math.max(oneLess, el);
  });
  if (oneLess !== -Infinity) res.unshift(oneLess);
  return res;
}
console.log(processUnsorted([30, 55, 10, 94, 75, 112], 69));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an input array `arr` and a value `val`:

1. Iterate over `arr`, splicing all elements greater than `val` into a separate array.
2. Append the maximum element left in `arr` to the new array.

```js
arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11];
val = 6;

new_arr = [];                             // Initialize new array
for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {        // Iterate over current array
    if (arr[i]>val) {                     // If the current element is greater than the given value
        new_arr.push(arr.splice(i, 1)[0]) // Splice it into the new array
        i--;                              // Decrement i so as to not skip any elements
    }
}

new_arr.unshift(Math.max(...arr))         // Add the closest value to the new array

console.log(new_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding the closest delta for numbers that are under the limit. Then filter all numbers that are under the limit, and the their delta with the limit is not equal to the delta you've found in the previous step.

Note: this assumes that the numbers are unique, but they don't have to be sorted.

```js
const fn = (arr, lim) => {
  const closestSmallerDelta = arr.reduce((acc, n) => 
    lim < n || lim - n > acc ? acc : lim - n
  , Infinity)

  return arr.filter(n => lim < n || lim - n === closestSmallerDelta)
}

console.log(fn([10, 30, 55, 75, 94, 112], 69));

// unsorted array
console.log(fn([112, 55, 75, 94, 10, 30], 69));
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the array is always sorted:

```js
const deleteSmallerButLastOne = (array , refNum ) =>{
  const finalArr = []
  for(let [index, num] of array.entries()){
    if(num < refNum && array[index + 1] >= refNum) finalArr.push(num)
    if(num > refNum) finalArr.push(num)
  }
  return finalArr
}
```

I took this approach instead of modifying the original array just in case you need it for later.